# Adding Release not on JIRA using rest API

Tags: jira, release, jira-rest-api

I am working on JIRA rest API. Using JIRA REST API I am able to create a release version on JIRA. I used below link to create a version.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-api-3-version-post

My next requirement to add a release note on a specific release version using the REST API. I would like to upload a text file as a release note.

Can you please suggest me how to add release note in JIRA using REST API.

JFYI: I am asking above requirement, as I am developing A web UI from where a user can add release version and can add a release note to that version.

Answer (score 0):

Jira doesn't support adding a file to a Version (Release). You can add a description, which is a simple text field, but that is it.